# JavaScript Leaflet Map not loading

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need multiple maps on my page, both 2Gis and Leaflet. The 2Gis itself is based on the Leaflet library. The 2Gis is working fine. The Leaflet works only without the 2Gis. Together with 2Gis it throws an error:

> "TypeError: Leaflet.tileLayer.Unwired is not a function" at this line:
>
> var myLeafletStreets = Leaflet.tileLayer.Unwired({ // <- ERROR HERE

Looks like there's a conflict between the 2 but I can't pin point where.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tL31gnxz/

If you remove the 2Gis bit:

```
DG.then(function() {
    InitTwoGisMap();
});
```

the Leaflet map loads fine.

What's the problem with Leaflet?

I'm using

```
var Leaflet = L.noConflict();
```

but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the plugin [Leaflet-2GIS](https://github.com/emikhalev/leaflet-2gis) to use Leaflet with 2GIS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
var myLeafletStreets = Leaflet.tileLayer({ // <- ERROR HERE
            key: 'pk.b2fa80c148d22bfa3f1d0e2347ddf3f6', 
            scheme: "streets",
        });
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5tpcxnv/)

Comment: The API is saying otherwise: https://locationiq.com/docs-html/index.html#desktop-maps-with-leaflet

Comment: That doesn't work. BTW it loads the 2Gis map into the Leaflet div.

Comment: @window.document, Why I use both 2Gis and Leaflet maps on the same page? I'm developing map plugin and they all must work together without conflicts.